# Best way of embedding a Java Properties file in a JAR

Tags: java, jar, embed, properties-file

Could anyone give me any pointers on how to embed a properties file inside a JAR. The JAR is to be added to the class path and accessed by another external JAR.

Process:
1) JAR1 calls getConfig method in JAR2
2) JAR2 loads the properties file from its internal resources
3) JAR2 returns properties file
4) JAR1 now has instance of properties file from JAR2

I've tried using this code in JAR2 for the getConfig method but can't get it working. The InputStream returns as null.

```
public class Config {
    public static InputStream getConfig() { 
    InputStream in = Config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
    return in;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you list the contents of the jar?

Comment: Where is the file stored in relationship to the classes?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config", Locale.ENGLISH);
```